# There exists a unique element of the row space of $A$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, where $b$ is in the column space of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am watching [a lecture](https://youtu.be/aW5JW6E24Jc?t=261) on multivariable mathematics by Theodore Shifrin on YouTube.

In this lecture, Professor Shifrin uses the following proposition:

> Let $A$ be a real matrix.
> Let $\mathbf{b}$ be any element of the column space of $A$.
> Then, there exists a unique element $\mathbf{x}$ of the row space of $A$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$.

I tried to prove this proposition, but I have no idea.

Please tell me the proof or a hint.

Comment: There's a proof in the body of the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585142/how-does-a-vector-b-in-the-column-space-come-from-a-vector-in-the-row-space), read the quoted part. Of course ,let me know if you understand it.

Comment: @peterwhy Thank you very much for your comment. I edited my question and I updated the lecture link to include a timestamp.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you very much for your link. I will read the link and will write if I understand it or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response, wish you a good read and satisfaction.

Comment: The argument is given in the very lecture. The point is that the row space is the orthogonal complement of the nullspace, and the solution set of $Ax=b$ is parallel to the nullspace.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I understand the uniqueness of $\mathbf{x}$ such that $A\mathbb{x}=\mathbf{b}$ and $x$ is an element of the row space of $A$. But I was not able to show that there exists an element $\mathbf{x}$ of the row space of $A$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much for your comment. I am sorry that my math ability is bad and especially my English listening ability is very very bad. I guess you give the proof of the uniqueness of $\mathbf{x}$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ is an element of the row space of $A$, where $\mathbf{b}$ is an element of the column space of $A$. I cannot prove that there exists an element $\mathbf{x}$ of the row space of $A$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$.

Comment: @tchappyha You do make the right point, after all there is no talk of existence in the part I asked you to read. Having said that, I will go through the lecture and let you know if something is discussed along these lines.

Comment: @tchappyha If you notice at the time 2:18, Prof. Shifrin asks to "recall" when there is a solution to $Ax = b$ at all, and he says that for this, the system $Ax = b$ has to be consistent, and that happens, when $b$ belongs to the column space (which a majority of the class knows). The answer to existence is then first given a video or two behind what you're currently studying. (why the system is consistent when $b$ is in the column space, and why $Ax = b$ has a solution if the system is consistent). The rest, you already know.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you very very much for your comments and your time. I will watch his lecture again. Thank you!

Comment: @tchappyha Welcome!

Comment: @TedShifrin I found the proposition 4.10 on p.183 "Multivariable Mathematics" by Theodore Shifrin which says "For each $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbf{C}(A)$, there is a unique vector $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbf{R}(A)$ so that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$". I will read this proof and watch your lectures again. Thank you very much for your great lecture series on YouTube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $b \in R(A)$, where $R$ denotes range. Note that the row space of $A$ is $R(A^*)$. It is easy to show that $R(A^*) = N(A)^{\perp}$.  From the direct sum decomposition $\mathbb{R}^n = N(A) \oplus N(A)^{\perp}$, it follows that $A : N(A)^{\perp} \to R(A)$ is an isomorphism. Thus $A : R(A^*) \to R(A)$ is an isomorphism. This implies the result.

This answer is not any more advanced than the others. I have only used two basic facts: 1. If $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\mathbb{R}^n = U \oplus U^{\perp}$. 2. If $\mathbb{R}^n = N(A) \oplus V$, then $A : V \to R(A)$ is a bijection (a linear bijection is called an isomorphism). 1. Can be proved by Gram-Schmidt, and should be in most linear algebra books, at least as an exercise. 2. Is easy to prove using the definition of $\oplus$.

Comment: Mason is using $R(A)$ for the column space of $A$. This is a popular convention, but confusing to someone for whom $R(A)$ denotes the row space.

Comment: Mason, Thank you very  much for your answer. Your answer is advanced for me, I believe your answer.

Comment: @tchappyha The answer is not advanced at all. I have only used two facts: 1. If $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\mathbb{R}^n = U \oplus U^{\perp}$. 2. If $\mathbb{R}^n = N(A) \oplus V$, then $A : V \to R(A)$ is a bijection (a linear bijection is called an isomorphism). 1. Can be proved by Gram-Schmidt, and should be in most linear algebra books, at least as an exercise. 2. Is easy to prove using the definition of $\oplus$.

Comment: @Mason Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I referred to "Multivariable Mathematics" by Theodore Shifrin (Proposition 4.10 and its proof on p.183).

Let $A$ be a real $m\times n$ matrix of rank $r$.
Then, $\dim\mathbf{R}(A)=r$, where $\mathbf{R}(A)$ is the row space of $A$.
Then, $\dim\mathbf{N}(A)=n-r$, where $\mathbf{N}(A)$ is the nullspace of $A$.
If $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbf{R}(A)\cap\mathbf{N}(A)$, then $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}=0$ since $\mathbf{R}(A)^\perp=\mathbf{N}(A)$.
So, $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$.
So, $\mathbf{R}(A)\cap\mathbf{N}(A)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$.
Let $\{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\dots,\mathbf{v}_r\}$ be a basis for $\mathbf{R}(A)$.
If $a_1A(\mathbf{v}_1)+a_2A(\mathbf{v}_2)+\dots+a_rA(\mathbf{v}_r)=\mathbf{0}$, then $A(a_1\mathbf{v}_1+a_2\mathbf{v}_2+\dots+a_r\mathbf{v}_r)=\mathbf{0}$.
So, $a_1\mathbf{v}_1+a_2\mathbf{v}_2+\dots+a_r\mathbf{v}_r\in\mathbf{R}(A)\cap\mathbf{N}(A)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$.
Since $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\dots,\mathbf{v}_r$ are linearly independent, $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_r=0$.
So, $A(\mathbf{v}_1),A(\mathbf{v}_2),\dots,A(\mathbf{v}_r)$ are linearly independent.
Since $A(\mathbf{v}_1),A(\mathbf{v}_2),\dots,A(\mathbf{v}_r)\in\mathbf{C}(A)$ and $\dim\mathbf{C}(A)=r$, $A(\mathbf{v}_1),A(\mathbf{v}_2),\dots,A(\mathbf{v}_r)$ span $\mathbf{C}(A)$ by a famous proposition.
So, if $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbf{C}(A)$, there exist $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_r$ such that $\mathbf{b}=b_1A(\mathbf{v}_1)+b_2A(\mathbf{v}_2)+\dots+b_rA(\mathbf{v}_r)=A(b_1\mathbf{v}_1+b_2\mathbf{v}_2+\dots+b_r\mathbf{v}_r)$.
And $b_1\mathbf{v}_1+b_2\mathbf{v}_2+\dots+b_r\mathbf{v}_r\in\mathbf{R}(A)$.
So, there exists $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbf{R}(A)$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ for any element $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbf{C}(A)$.
Let $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbf{C}(A)$.
Suppose that $A(\mathbf{x}_1)=\mathbf{b}$ and $A(\mathbf{x}_2)=\mathbf{b}$, where $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2\in\mathbf{R}(A)$.
Then $A(\mathbf{x}_1)=A(\mathbf{x}_2)$.
So, $A(\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2)=\mathbf{0}$.
Since $\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2\in\mathbf{R}(A)\cap\mathbf{N}(A)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$, $\mathbf{x}_1=\mathbf{x}_2$.
So, there exists a unique $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbf{R}(A)$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ for any element $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbf{C}(A)$.